# How to handle like one two separate date and time fields?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, datetime, parameters, mongoid

How to make two separated fields so can be handled to one `datetime field` in database?

I'm using jquery datetime picker that puts values like value in code example below.

Parameters includes only field with time but ignores field with date.

If I comment field with time then date is sent and saved but parameter looks like "2013-23-02" and it isn't forwarded like multi parameter.

```
#model
field :start_at, type: DateTime

#view
= f.text_field :start_at, :value => "2013-02-23"
= f.text_field :start_at, :value => "20:20:20"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use virtual attributes and callback (this is not tested but you should get the idea)

```
# model
attr_writer :start_at_time, :start_at_date

before_validation :build_start_at

def start_at_date
  @start_at_date ||= start_at.to_date
end

def start_at_time
  @start_at_time ||= start_at.strftime("%H:%M")
end

def build_start_at
  self.start_at = Time.parse "#{start_at_date} #{start_at_time}"
end    

# view
= f.text_field :start_at_date
= f.text_field :start_at_time
```

Comment: I thought that it can be get a more standard way. I think I'll make a hidden field like one with date and time on the client side.